# A simple transposition cipher

Tags: java, arrays, encryption, multidimensional-array

I need to write a simple column transposition cipher program.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public static String transpositionCipher(String text, int N) {
    String output = "";
    char[][] split = new char[N][text.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < text.length(); j++) {
            split[i][j] = text.charAt(i * text.length() + j);
            System.out.println(split[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Bellow are the inputs and expected outputs of my program:

**INPUT #1**

```
text = "New atak", N = 3
```

Transposition matrix:

```
N e w
_ a t
a k _
```

**OUPUT #1**

```
"N aeakwt"
```

**INPUT #2**

```
text = "NOS ATACAN CON CARBUNCO", N = 5
```

Transposition matrix:

```
N O S _ A
T A C A N
_ C O N _
C A R B U
N C O _ _
```

**OUPUT #2**

```
"NT CNOACACSCORO ANB AN U"
```

Comment: Your current code does not compile. You're missing a return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to *javadoc* comments for method `cifradoTrans` in below code. Note that I replace spaces with underscores for better visualization.

```java
public class CipherSq {

    /**
     * Places characters of <var>cadena</var> in a matrix with <var>numberOfColumnsInMatrix</var>
     * columns and as many rows as required in order to hold all characters of <var>cadena</var>.
     * Stores the characters in rows, i.e. first character in <var>cadena</var> is in first row,
     * first column of matrix. Second character of <var>cadena</var> is in first row, second column
     * of matrix, and so on. Then a string is created by traversing the matrix column by column and
     * concatenating the matrix elements, i.e. first character of returned string is character in
     * first row, first column of matrix. Second character in string is second row, first column of
     * matrix and so on.
     * 
     * @param cadena                  - string to manipulate.
     * @param numberOfColumnsInMatrix - number of columns in matrix.
     * 
     * @return Manipulated string.
     */
    public static String cifradoTrans(String cadena, int numberOfColumnsInMatrix) {
        cadena = cadena.replace(' ', '_');
        char[] characters = cadena.toCharArray();
        int len = cadena.length();
        int rows = (int) Math.ceil((double) len / numberOfColumnsInMatrix);
        char[][] matrix = new char[rows][numberOfColumnsInMatrix];
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < len; i++) {
            col = i % numberOfColumnsInMatrix;
            if (col == 0) {
                row = i / numberOfColumnsInMatrix;
                System.out.println();
            }
            matrix[row][col] = characters[i];
            System.out.print(characters[i] + " ");
        }
        for (col++; col < numberOfColumnsInMatrix; col++) {
            matrix[row][col] = '_';
            System.out.print(matrix[row][col] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(System.lineSeparator());
        i = 0;
        char[] newCharacters = new char[rows * numberOfColumnsInMatrix];
        for (col = 0; col < numberOfColumnsInMatrix; col++) {
            for (row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
                newCharacters[i++] = matrix[row][col];
            }
        }
        return new String(newCharacters);
    }

    /**
     * Recognizes two command-line arguments. First is string to manipulate.
     * Second is number of columns in matrix.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 1) {
            System.out.println(cifradoTrans(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1])));
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("ARGS: string int");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run above code with [command-line] arguments `"NOS ATACAN CON CARBUNCO"` and `5`, I get the following output:

```
N O S _ A 
T A C A N 
_ C O N _ 
C A R B U 
N C O _ _ 

NT_CNOACACSCORO_ANB_AN_U_
```

Comment: The amount of work put into this answer is dangerously disproportional to the effort made by the OP. :)